# How to print html string as html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, text

If just for example I do:

```
var = "<a>Asd</a>";

<span>{{ var }}</span>
```

The string is printed like text and not as html, so how do I print the html ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should be using [`ng-bind-html` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml).

> Creates a binding that will innerHTML the result of evaluating the
>   expression into the current element in a secure way.

```
<ANY ng-bind-html="{expression}">
   ...
</ANY>
```

Comment: expression can be variable or function. lets consider `var htmlString='<somehtml />'`, then it should be  `<span ng-bind-html='htmlString'></span>`

Comment: now you need to reference ng-sanitize to accomplish this. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Answer (score 10):

Before using the **ng-bind-html** directive you must include the **$sanitize** service or it will throw an error.

*Error: $sce:unsafe
Require a safe/trusted value
Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.*

```html
Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$sce/unsafe
    at Error (native)
```

The right way:

```js
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

```js
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML = '<a href="#">Hello, World!</a>';
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 6):

You can also try something like that:

```
    app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
      return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
      };
    }]);
```

and then, in view:

```
    ng-bind-html=" myHTML | to_trusted"
```

Comment: Where is this added in the angular project?