# How i can use html in angular controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying create superscript html in my angular

```
$scope.Volume = 'm<sup>3</sup>';
```

I always get html like this

```
<div class="ng-binding">Volume<br>(m&lt;sup&gt;3&lt;/sup&gt;)</div>
```

Becuase of above html generated, it alwyas shows `m<sup>3</sup>` on render page rather than desired output i.e. m superscript 3.

How i can use html in angular controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular js - how to print html string as html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231630/angular-js-how-to-print-html-string-as-html)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can bind the html with

```
<div ng-bind-html="Volume"></div>
```

See the official documentation:
See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: How i can do it inside controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HTML in templates directly. You can use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), but it will by default also strip out potentially problematic tags like `<script>`. So you also need to include [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize).